# integral of $\frac {\sqrt {x+4}}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

So I'm trying to compute $\int\frac {\sqrt {x+4}}xdx$ . They tell me to use a substitution to make it a rational function. I set $u=\sqrt{x+4}$ and got the integrand $\frac {2u^2}{u^2-4} du$. With polynomial long division and partial fractions, I arrived at the integral of $$\int 1+\frac {1}{u+2}-\frac {1}{u-2}du$$ giving the answer of $\sqrt {x+4} + \ln|\sqrt {x+4} -2| - \ln|\sqrt {x+4} +2| + C$, which is wrong.

Comment: Your solution is correct, modulo a factor of $2$ .  Why do you believe otherwise?

Comment: You can also do it in the following manner: $x=2\tan\theta\implies dx=2\sec^2\theta\ d\theta\implies\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sqrt{x+4}}{x}dx=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{4\sec^3\theta}{2\tan\theta}d\theta=2\displaystyle\int\dfrac{d\theta}{\sin\theta \cos^2\theta}=2\displaystyle\int\csc\theta\sec^2\theta\ d\theta=2\displaystyle\int \csc\theta\ d\theta+2\displaystyle\int \csc\theta\tan^2\theta\ d\theta=2\displaystyle\int \csc\theta\ d\theta+2\displaystyle\int \sec\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta$. Each of which can be evaluated easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ be the integral

$$I=\int \frac{\sqrt{x+4}}{x}\,dx$$

Now, substitute $u=\sqrt{x+4}$ to that $x=u^2-4$ and $dx=2u\,du$.  Then, $I$ becomes

$$\begin{align}
I&=2\int \frac{u^2}{u^2-4}\,du\\\\
&=2\int \left(\frac{u^2-4+4}{u^2-4}\right)\,du\\\\
&=2u+2\int\left(\frac{1}{u-2}-\frac{1}{u+2}\right)\,du\\\\
&=2u+2\log\left|\frac{u-2}{u+2}\right|+C\\\\
&=2\sqrt{x+4}+2\log\left|\frac{\sqrt{x+4}-2}{\sqrt{x+4}+2}\right|+C
\end{align}$$